# How to hide or display text and tags with PHP?

Tags: php

I was wondering how would hide the text Location if the city state and country were not present and how would I let it display if any of the variables were present?

```
<p>Location:
<?php
 if (!empty($city))
     {
        echo $city .',';
     }

 if (!empty($state))
     {
        echo $state;
     }

 if (!empty($country))
     {
        echo ' ' . $country;
     }
?>    
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a PHP block as well:

```
<?php

// Check if any of them is not empty.
if(!empty($city) || !empty($state) || !empty($country)){
    echo "<p>Location:";
    if (!empty($city))
    {
        echo $city .',';
    }
    if (!empty($state))
    {
        echo $state;
    }
    if (!empty($country))
    {
        echo ' ' . $country;
    }
    echo "</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
<?php
 $address = "";
 if (!empty($city))
     {
        $address_parts[] = $city;
     }

 if (!empty($state))
     {
        $address_parts[] = $state;
     }

 if (!empty($country))
     {
        $address_parts[] = $country;
     }
$address = implode( ", ", $address_parts);
if (!empty($address)) 
{
 echo   "<p>Location: " . $address . "</p>";
}
?>
```

Build the address up and then test if the address is still empty before displaying location.

**Edit**
Changed how the address is built up. Rather than concatenate everything, the address parts are added to an array and then imploded with the appropriate separator.

Answer (score 0):

in not exactly same but a similar problem, i used this method.

may be this helps you too:)

```
<?php
function publish($buffer){
global $location;
if (empty($location))
    $buffer="";
return $buffer;
}
ob_start("publish");

$location=$_GET["location"];
echo "Location: $location";

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

test the url with location parameter and without a parameter. 
And you can find more detail about this in [php.net output control functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)